# Kubuntu update-initramfs results in: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device /swapfile

Tags: kubuntu, encryption, cryptsetup

Lately, I did a fresh install of kubuntu (coming from linux mint) where I also encypted the drive and swapfile. During booting I got the error:

> Cryptsetup waiting for encrytped source device /swapfile.

After some searching I found that a command called `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` should solve it. However, I get some errors I cannot resolve:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: cryptswap1: couldn't determine device type, assuming
default (plain).
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device /swapfile
cryptsetup: WARNING: cryptswap1: key file /dev/loop0 has insecure ownership,
see /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.Debian.gz.
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap1 uses a key file
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-0
I: (/dev/mapper/cryptswap1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-35-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: cryptswap1: couldn't determine device type, assuming
default (plain).
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device /swapfile
cryptsetup: WARNING: cryptswap1: key file /dev/loop0 has insecure ownership,
see /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.Debian.gz.
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap1 uses a key file
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-0
I: (/dev/mapper/cryptswap1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

The content of the /etc/crypttab file is `cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/loop0 swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256`

The command `lsblk -f` gives the following:

```
NAME         FSTYPE   FSVER LABEL      UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0        swap     1                7ab8406f-ea13-4984-8211-b9dd27a0677c                 
└─cryptswap1 swap     1     cryptswap1 4cd157f7-3d8d-4893-aea8-be54200244e1                [SWAP]
```

Is somebody able to help me here? I probably has something to do with the crypttab file but I don't know what to change.

Comment: Okay, during the installation of kubuntu I used the default settings (not using lvm). Later I followed the instuctions below. During the encryption of the swapfile, it complained there was no swapfile, hence the situation I am in now: https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/

Comment: This isn't an error only an info.

Comment: @Nmath I indeed went for lvm encryption with an new ubuntu installation this time. Now the entire drive is encrypted which is also fine (maybe even better then the home drive alone). Thanks for the help